# strcmp always returning 1

Tags: c, strcmp

The variable "id" used in the following code is a global variable which is got from a separate function. It is declared and used as a string. 
The check variable is an integer.

```
    do{

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\tEnter the id of the account you want to transfer to: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&account_id);
    check=strcmp(id,account_id);

    printf("%d",check);//This is just a temporary check to see what strcmp is returning

    if(check<0)
    {
        printf("\n\t\tYou cannot transfer to you own account!\n");
    }
```

Problem is in the title. Check is always 1 no matter what value is input by me. It does change to -1 if I compare the varibles in the reverse order (ie strcmp(account_id,id);).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post declaration of `account_id`. Print value of `id` and `account_id` prior to `strcmp()`. Always check the result of `scanf()`. Do not `fflush(stdin)`, as it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: What is your question? If `account_id` is either an array of `char` or a `char*`, drop the `&` in the `scanf` call, though that's not likely to cause any visible problems. Try printing the values of `id` and `account_id`. Your test `if(check < 0)` checks whether `id` is lexicographically less than `account_id`, which seems inconsistent with your error message.  Oh, and drop the `fflush(stdin);` `fflush` is for output streams.

Comment: And `scanf` with a `"%s"` format is inherently unsafe, but you can worry about that later (it's ok as long as the number of characters actually entered doesn't overflow the target array).

Answer (score 1):

although you do not show us the values of `id` or `account_id`, I expect your problem is the hidden Newline.

I'm guessing that:

```
id = "12345";
account_id = "12345\n";
```

*the \n is from when you hit enter!*

You can check this in a debugger, or even with a printf:

```
printf("Lengths are: %d and %d\n", strlen(id), strlen(account_id));
```

As a result, they do not compare equal.

Comment: If he reads the value of `account_id` with `scanf("%s",&account_id)` (or, more correctly, with `scanf("%s",&account_id)`), then it's not going to have a newline. `"%s"` reads a white-space delimited word. And don't use `"%d"` to print the result of `strlen`; either cast to `int` or use `"%zu"`, which is the correct format for `size_t` (if your implementation supports it; even 15 years after C99, not all do).

Comment: at least one popular compiler does not support `%z`.   Otherwise, fair point.